# Database image to TImage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

why is this code not working:

Saving images is just fine with this code (also I see the image in the reports):

```
   gallery.append;
   gallery.FieldByName('Image').Assign(pic.Picture.Bitmap);
   gallery.post;
```

however this code:

```
Gallery.Insert;
S := CreateBlobStream(gallery.FieldByName('Image'), bmWrite);
Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SaveToStream(S);
gallery.Post;
S.Free;
```

results in error 'DataSet is not in edit or insert mode'. So I used the first one.

but getting it back to the form in Timage results in "invalid bitmap format"

```
var S : TStream ;
s := gallery.CreateBlobStream(gallery.FieldByName('Image'), bmRead);
Pic.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(S);
s.Free;
```

the error shows with any image. I tried the DBimage as well using the tutorial from About.com and keep getting error.
the Database is Access 2010 and the image field is OLE (blob).
Kinda stuck.

s

Comment: Try setting the position of s to 0, after reading from the field and before loading the bitmap, in the last snippet.

Comment: `
var S : TStream ;
s := gallery.CreateBlobStream(gallery.FieldByName('Image'),   bmRead);
s.position :=0;
    Pic.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(S);
    s.Free;


Still give an error "Bitmap Image is not valid"

Comment: BTW most tutorials say I should add JPEG to my uses ...when I do that I get the JPEG underlined with a red curly line with an error..so I think the tutorials are outdated.

Comment: Is the field type binary?

Comment: the Database is Access 2010 and the image field is OLE (blob).

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURE IT OUT:

this is how you can display a JPG image from an Access database to Timage:

1. the Access database field is OLE (or blob).
2. Save an image to the database using this code

   gallery.append;
   gallery.FieldByName('Image').Assign(pic.Picture.Bitmap); 
   gallery.post;

the gallery is the AdoTable and Image is Access field name containing the image.
Now to display the image back into Delphi Timage component:
1. in the Uses clause the one that contains the unit uses (File --Use Unit) put:

```
Uses Jpeg
```

then use this code to display the image:

```
var
jpg:TJPegImage;

begin
jpg :=TjpegImage.Create;
jpg.Assign(TblobField(gallery.FieldByName('Image')));
pic.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(jpg);
jpg.Free;
end;
```

How cool is that.